# What is the different between a parameter and a local variable?

Tags: javascript

Apologies for what must seem like a *very* stupid question.

I'm currently working through codecadamy, and this is throwing me off:

```
 var greeting = function(name) {
    name = "sausage";
    console.log(name); 
};

greeting(name);
```

I understand that I will get `sausage`

Why don't I just write `var name = "sausage";`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name` in `function(name)` is a parameter. That is, it is used to pass data into the function. But, parameters are local variables. Assigning a value to `name` inside the function is a little strange though. I would assume you want to do something like this:

```
 var greeting = function(name) {         
     console.log(name); 
  };

  greeting("sausage");
```

In this version of the code you are passing the value "sausage" into the function via the parameter `name`. This is useful because you can call the function many times and each time the function may print a different value depending on what you pass.

Comment: Ah, that's incredibly clear. So it's kind of like a placeholder? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your function definition:

```
function(name) {
```

name is already being declared. It is a parameter for the function. If you want to change name, you can, but you don't need to use var to declare it as a new variable.

On the other hand, if you wanted to add, say, flavor, you should use var then since it is not already defined.

```
var flavor = 'savory';
```

In this case, flavor is a local variable and name is a parameter. A parameter is a type of local variable that is declared with the function declaration, but a local variable isn't necessarily a parameter because it may be declared elsewhere in the function.

Comment: Thanks. So could I then write: function(name, flavor); ?

Comment: Having parameters means the data needs to come from somewhere else (or at least that you are expecting it). If you did function(name, flavor), then when you call it, you'd have to do
greeting('sausage', 'savory');
to pass in the values for it to use.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there is no real difference.

Without giving you the huge background here, you have to understand that in the underlaying implementation, a special object (not a javascript object, on C/C++ level) is formed which is called *Activation Object* (ES3) or *Lexical Environment Record* (ES5).

However, this *hash / object* structure is used to store

- variables declared by `var`
- formal parameters
- function declarations

As you can see, both `var` variables and parameters are stored in this structure.

This construct is most likely used to have somewhat *default values* for not passed in arguments. In a real world example, this would probably look more like

```
var greeting = function( name ) {
    name = name || 'default';

    console.log( name );
};

greeting('john');  // 'john'
greeting();        // 'default'
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are a general programming construct and are necessary to do anything sane in the world programming (dealing with masses of global variables is *not* sane.

`var name` would declare a new variable in the function scope that would override the value of the parameter `name`, so you would not be able to use the parameter anymore.

The CodeAcadamy example is a bit strange because it's rare that you want to override a parameter's value -- especially before you have used it.

Comment: its actually not so rare, thinking of *default values* for not passed in arguments. `param = param || 'default';`